# Missing some id's from user table

Tags: symfony, doctrine

When I check my table, discover I have missing some id's from user table.
I have entity User with attribute $id private use annotation
Something is missing?

For Symfony version 4.2.8
PHP 7.2.18

```
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Serializer\Groups("base")
 * @var int
 * @SWG\Property(description="The unique identifier of the user.")
```